# converting JSON object to xml (with order as per the input)

Tags: java, json, xml

I am trying to create the XML using the JSON.
here is the input:

```
String message={StoreMasterRequest:{Message:{StandardBusinessDocumentHeader:{HeaderVersion:'1.0',Sender:{a:{Identifier:{body:'1',Authority:'EAN.UCC'}}},Receiver:{b:{Identifier:{body:'123',Authority:'EAN.UCC'}}},DocumentIdentification:{Standard:'AH-VI Specific Standard',TypeVersion:'1.0',InstanceIdentifier:'23',Type:'Store Master',MultipleType:'false',CreationDateAndTime:'2016-06-28T15&&54&&17'}},Payload:{StoreMaster:{MessageID:'23',MessageCreated:'2016-06-28T15&&54&&15',StoreNo:'151',LMExemptionStart:'',LMExemptionEnd:'',StoreGLN:'8710400034390',CountryCode:'NL',Street:'Amstel',HouseNumber:'900',PostalCode:'1185AL',City:'AMSTELVEEN',State:'HOLLAND',StreetDelivery:'AmstelDel',HouseNumberDelivery:'464',PostalCodeDelivery:'1185AL'}}}}}
```

in my java code I am using the following.

```
xml=org.json.XML.toString(new org.json.JSONObject(message));
```

the output of the XML is coming as

```
<StoreMasterRequest><Message><Payload><StoreMaster><Street>Amstel</Street><City>AMSTELVEEN</City><StoreGLN>8710400034390</StoreGLN><StreetDelivery>AmstelDel</StreetDelivery><PostalCodeDelivery>1185AL</PostalCodeDelivery><StoreNo>151</StoreNo><LMExemptionStart/><PostalCode>1185AL</PostalCode><State>HOLLAND</State><MessageID>23</MessageID><HouseNumberDelivery>464</HouseNumberDelivery><LMExemptionEnd/><HouseNumber>900</HouseNumber><CountryCode>NL</CountryCode><MessageCreated>2016-06-28T15:54:15</MessageCreated></StoreMaster></Payload><StandardBusinessDocumentHeader><DocumentIdentification><Standard>AH-VI Specific Standard</Standard><InstanceIdentifier>23</InstanceIdentifier><TypeVersion>1.0</TypeVersion><CreationDateAndTime>2016-06-28T15:54:17</CreationDateAndTime><Type>Store Master</Type><MultipleType>false</MultipleType></DocumentIdentification><Sender><a><Identifier><body>1</body><Authority>EAN.UCC</Authority></Identifier></a></Sender><HeaderVersion>1.0</HeaderVersion><Receiver><b><Identifier><body>123</body><Authority>EAN.UCC</Authority></Identifier></b></Receiver></StandardBusinessDocumentHeader></Message></StoreMasterRequest>
```

I see there is no order in the generated XML file as per the input given string.i tried overriding the JSONObject class by using linkedhashmap.
but it didn't worked out and got encoding issues. I am using JSON 1.5.jar and decompiled using CFR. I have taken the source from this.I am using JDK1.7 in my local. Can any one suggest which one is the best way to order the JSON object.

Thank You

Comment: A JSON object does not guranee order of its keyset. The keys and respective vales may get shuffled theoratically and it mostly happens when transmitted over network. Although motly order remains intact when handling offline data. If you want to be sure about order of keys in your design then probably add ordering propertier for your objects or achieve it by using  a specific naming convention for keys in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try the `json-to-xml()` function in XSLT 3.0 (implemented in Saxon 9.7) which retains the order of entries in a map. However the output will then need to be transformed: The XSLT function turns JSON keys into XML attribute values

```
<string key="Street">Amstel</string>
```

because you can't be sure that JSON keys will be valid XML element names.